# Performance of Jquery vs CSS tooltips?

Tags: jquery, css

I was wondering, if I had say - 100 tooltips what would be the performance comparison if they were jquery or css based? From my understanding, with CSS tooltips, the physical tooltip is created for each item and hidden from view until a user hovers over it - while a jquery tooltip should be only one item that changes content when its hovered upon. Or am I wrong? What do you think I should go with? Thanks!

Comment: Does it matter? You're only going to display one tooltip at a time anyway... right?

Comment: That's correct, however if you have 100 items hidden, they should still have some toll on performance.

Comment: i found css tooltips to be pretty limiting with what you can put inside them. Usually just plain text.

Comment: I guess the only difference would be manipulating the DOM once in a while versus loading extra items in the DOM. I don't see any memory or network performance diff.

Comment: It depends on how you're implementing tooltips. What do you mean by jQuery based or CSS based?

Comment: CSS based tooltips don't need jquery to operate. You have to create a separate tag usually like this `<a href="">text<span>tooltip</span></a>`, while in jquery tooltips you usually add the content in the `title` attribute and it creates the content for you.

Comment: @BoltClock. It might very well matter. [See here](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-ww-monthly-201212-201212-bar). IE7 is used by 0.8% of the internet using population. If your site has 1,000,000 (one million) unique visitors a month, 8,000 (eight thousand) of them are (statistically) likely to be using IE7. That's a lot of unique people!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on how many elements will have tooltips and how often they are displayed. For example, if you have few elements to apply tooltips to and they are displayed often, your CSS approach will be better. If you have lots of elements to apply tooltips to and they are not displayed often, your JS approach will be better.

It also depends on the size of the tooltips. The only way to answer your question is to actually try both and see which performs best. Also consider JS is much slower in some browsers. IE 6/7 will not perform well with 50tooltips/s using JS. CSS will still not be great but likely better than JS. You need to try both implementations and test on various browser versions.

Comment: Thanks flem. What would you classify as display often? Say, you have a tooltip for each table row, and you have a table with 50 rows that the user scrolls through with his/her mouse (meaning, he might go through some 50 tooltips in a few seconds). Would jqeury still be better?

Comment: That's too open a question to answer. It also depends on the size of the tooltips. The only way to answer your question is to actually try both and see which performs best. Also consider JS is much slower in some browsers. IE 6/7 will not perform well with 50tooltips/s using JS. CSS will still not be great but likely better than JS. You need to try both implementations and test on various browser versions.